# Get Server header of HTTP server

Tags: python, http

I want to get the `Server` header of HTTP with Python. I don't know how can I get it, I looked at the `RFC` of `Hypertext Transfer Protocol` and got into the `Server` section.

```
 The Server response-header field contains information about the
   software used by the origin server to handle the request. The field
   can contain multiple product tokens (section 3.8) and comments
   identifying the server and any significant subproducts. The product
   tokens are listed in order of their significance for identifying the
   application.
```

How can we get it ? I can guess that with `os` or `platform`, etc.

Comment: How do you make the HTTP request?

Comment: @KlausD. I build my own http server, and I want to include the `server` header in the response headers

Comment: That's pretty much the opposite of your question.

Comment: @KlausD. Why fam?

Comment: Your question asks how to **get** server headers which is a client task and your comment asks how to **set** server headers which is a server task.

Comment: It is always a good idea to give more context in your question. What is the actual overall thing you are trying to accomplish? In this case, it sounds like you are writing your own HTTP Server. Once you establish the context, ask your question in that context.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to:

- Send HTTP requests to a web server and retrieve the 'Server' header
  from the HTTP response.
- You want to use python.

'requests' is a very popular lib to make HTTP requests (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Here is a code sample very may guide you achieving what you need

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://example.com")
print(response.headers['Server'])
```